# open a new activity in thread in android studio

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I have a thread that calls a Soap webservice where I log in the user and then display a toast to say "Welcome" + username ... but now in that UI thread I would also like the page to navigate from the login screen to the main landing page but i recieve an error when i am doing that. below is code and error.

**Thread Code**

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {


                        String Response = "";
                        HT.call(Soap_action_Temp,envelope);
                        SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

                        Settings.setUserLoginResult(resultString.getValue().toString());
                        Response = Settings.getUserLoginResult().toString();

                        if (Response != "")
                        {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,"Welcome " + username + " !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,LandingPage.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();
```

**Issue**

The picture below shows the activity being empty ? is there any reason for this ?

[image]

Logcat is showing me nothing out of the ordinary, but my app crashes and says "App name has stopped working"

can any one please help we with why this is failing? or is my code wrong?

**EDIT**

The app isn't even hitting the catch event i put in .

**Here is the logcat entry after clicking login and appcrashes**

```
  07-17 07:52:33.145  10329-10329/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Ellipsys.embizomobile/com.example.Ellipsys.embizomobile.LandingPage}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:108)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
            at com.example.Ellipsys.embizomobile.LandingPage.onCreate(LandingPage.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You don't need to put two `runOnUiThread`s. You can just move the `startActivity..` part to the first one. Secondly, if the app is crashing, there's gotta be something that  the logcat says.

Comment: dont put TOAST notifications in Background Processes

Comment: @Prag's it is not on a background process, it is on a UI thread, because the Soap call is in a background thread i must create a UI thread to show the Toast on screen

Comment: try to remove it and run your process

Comment: @Prag's i took it out but nothing changed, still breaks without a toast notification lol

Comment: @ShivamVerma Edited question and put the intent into same UI thread :) , still looking on logcat for any errors.

Comment: are all levels of logging enabled on your ddms ? There's an option where you select the level of logging you want.

Comment: @ShivamVerma logcat entry added :) i had to set the filter to errors  then saw what happened thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the exception is :      `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Add this to the activity tag in the manifest : `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`

Comment: Okay that worked? but before i accept, can you please explain why this is needed? and why the screen looks different?

Comment: My guess is that you're extending ActionBarActivity in the activity you're trying to open which needs this for compatibility with previous android versions.

Comment: What you can also do is to just extend Activity if you don't really need it.

Comment: very cool ... thanks for taking your time to help me :) appreciate it